# Why I cannot put project name when to connect Bitbucket with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

I choose to build pipeline script SCM, the project name does not appear when I put my project name.

It says:

> Something went wrong when trying to contact Bitbucket Server: Provided credentials cannot access the resource

When I try to put my project name.

I already put name as my Bitbucket server project where it says:

`Enter the name of the Bitbucket Server project containing the repository you want Jenkins to build from. To find a project, start typing. If it doesn't appear in the search results, the credentials that you've chosen may not have read access to it and you'll need to provide different credentials.`

but I'm still getting an error.

May I know how to make it possible to deploy source code from Bitbucket server into Jenkins server?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-FugzVYJQU, I try to follow this tutrorial, but stuck at 3.49 mins when to put project name.

Comment: Did you generate your Personal Access Token from bitbucket (PAT) and use that in the manage jenkins page?

Comment: Yes, I did generate and put in Jenkins configuration in Bitbucket Server Integration but put none as credentials. When I test the connection. It says: Jenkins can connect with Bitbucket Server. But when trying to put project name in pipeline script scm, something wrong when trying to contact Bitbucket Server.

Comment: You have to add your Bitbucket PAT in Jenkins credentials and then use that to connect to bitbucket, it will work then

Comment: I have added the steps in a post, you can mark that as answer so it will be helpful for anyone that refers in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to be followed

1. In bitbucket create a personal access token
2. Create a credential in Jenkins for the above personal access token
3. In Jenkins job configuration, use the credential setup in (2) to use for connecting to the bitbucket.